# How to draw a rectangle around keypoints of a pose?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image of a hand and I passed it through a pre trained **[hand pose estimation](https://www.kaggle.com/changethetuneman/openpose-model)** model
 and got this output. 
**Output**
[image]

**Task**
Now I want to draw a rectangle around the hand to carry out some tasks.
 How do I draw a rectangle around a hand with just using those keypoints(not using another model).

[image]

*In case if you're interested to know why I need that rectangle.*
I want to normalize all the points inside the rectangle to range of (0,1) by dividing each point with width and height of rectangle and top left points to 0s and bottom points to 1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used OpenCV in quite a while, hence the simplest approach I can think of without relying on it's methods would be to use the list of keypoint locations and find the min/max x and y values.

That is, loop through the list of points (which I assume each have a given x and y) and store the minimum x and y, as well as maximum x and y. To do this you will want to initialise the variables according to your image's size, or alternatively store all x and y in their own separate lists and perform min and max functions accordingly.

The rectangle therefore is defined by the 2 corner points of (x_min, y_min) and (x_max, y_max), which you can also extract width and height from using subtraction. Make sure your drawing reference matches up with the xy-reference of the points. To actually draw the rectangle you can refer to the code here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html